# Form Inputs Within Elixir List Comprehension

Tags: forms, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am displaying a table of students and want each row to have a form element that can be used to alter information about that student. What I currently have (shown below) only works for the last student in the table since it would appear the `:manual_choice` and `:student_id` aren't unique form fields from row to row.

How do I make this list comprehension across all students generate unique form fields for each row of the table so that when I submit the form, I can update whichever student had a manual_choice chosen for them?

```
<%= form_for @changeset, assignments_path(@conn, :manual_assign), fn f -> %>
<table id="students" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Student Name</th>
      <th>Assigned Project</th>
      <th>Override Assignment</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%= for student <- @all_students do %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= student.student_name %></td>
        <td><%= student.assigned_project %></td>
        <td class="text-right">
          <div class="form-group">
              <%= select f, :manual_choice, @projects, class: "form-control", id: "manual_choice" %>
              <%= text_input f, :student_id, class: "form-control", value: student.id, style: "display:none" %>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why not put the `form_for` around the 2 inputs (select and text_input)? You can have multiple forms on the page and submitting one would only submit the value of that form.

Comment: That could work. Then I would need a submit button for each row, correct?

Comment: Yes. Do you want to be able to change multiple students at once?

Answer (score 0):

As the esteemed Dogbert points out, perhaps a lower-maintenance approach is to just create a separate form for each Student record; clicking the submit button would submit only the data for that record.

But if you specifically want one giant table with one submit button at the bottom (a better fit for some bulk-updating situations), maybe you could include an incremented counter in each input's name. A simple example might look like this:

```
<%= @all_students |> Enum.with_index |> Enum.each(fn(student, index) -> %>
  ...
    <%= select f, "student_#{index}[manual_choice]", @projects, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= text_input f, "student_#{index}[id]", value: student.id, style: "display:none" %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Notes:

1. I use `Enum.with_index` and `Enum.each` to iterate over the students list, instead of `for student <- @students`. I come from the Ruby world, where `for` loops are frowned upon; I've found that I can always make do with `Enum.each` or `Enum.map`, I haven't yet needed to use the `for` construct.
2. For the select & input elements, I provide a string that will be unique for each element. For example the fifth row's select name should be `student_4[manual_choice]`.
3. I haven't tested all this; I'm just spitballing. I'm confident that this general approach will work well, but not clear on the exact semantics. For example I don't know if `Enum.each` will actually print out any markup / content generated; `Enum.map` might work better.
4. The controller endpoint that receives the submitted form must be able to make sense of the params and iterate over each student's form data. I suspect this is easy (it's super easy in the Rails world) but haven't done this yet in Elixir/Phoenix.

In case #4 gives you trouble, maybe a simpler approach would be to name each input element using the array syntax, like: `"students[manual_choice][]"` and `"students[id][]"`. That way, in the controller action you could iterate over the `students[id]` nested params, and trust that each entry corresponds with the same index of `students[manual_choice]`.